# is rospy.Publisher.publish() thread safe?

Tags: ros, rospy, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Want to publish() in main and also in child thread on one rospy.Publisher(),is this safe?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257245/is-rospy.publisher.publish()-thread-safe?/) by [dyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/29703/dyan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2017-03-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, rospy.Publisher() is thread safe.

Before publishing a message it acquires a lock for thread safety and releases it after the message is sent.

You can see the source code here: http://docs.ros.org/api/rospy/html/rospy.topics-pysrc.html#Publisher.publish

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2017-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2